# Hiding cells in pyvista 3d plots using vtk

Tags: 3d, visualization, vtk, pyvista

In Jupyter notebooks, using Pyvista for 3D visualization, we need to wrap the mesh to vtk first and then convert the cell data to point data and then we plot the mesh accordingly, I need to plot the system but hiding a specific cell of the mesh, remove cells, delete cell attributes are not working.

I have used hide cells, remove cells, DeleteCells but nothing is working in vtk.